# SpecFlow codebehind file generated but not attached to feature file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I'm pretty new to SpecFlow and I've been having problems with the codebehind files. I can see them being generated in my files, but they're not visible in VS, meaning the codebehind files are not attached to the feature file. This leads to the following error:

```
    ---- System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Configuration system failed to initialize
    -------- System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Unrecognized configuration section specFlow. (\bin\Debug\somefile.dll.config line 52)
    ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: FixtureData fixtureData
```

Deleting the feature.cs and rebuilding the solution does not help.

Comment: Have you installed the Specflow VS plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowForVisualStudio) ?

Comment: Is this .NET Core?

Comment: I have installed the SpecFlow plugin, and yes, this is .NET Core.

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow did you install?

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded an extension called "File Nesting". When I build I add the generated feature file as an existing item, then I nest it in the feature file using the extension.

Comment: This may solve your problem but definitely doesn't sound like something that you should need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar problems when I upgraded from direct DLL reference to Specflow version 2.2.0 - to NuGet reference of version 3.1.7.4.

I needed to "Show All Files" in Visual Studio to see the code behind file at a sibling level to its associated Feature file (this used to be an associated child file of the feature file in the previous Specflow version).

I also need to use the "Include In Project" context menu item on the code behind file for it to show up in Visual Studios "Test Explorer".
See Open issue in github, which states that you have to use the NuGet reference to get the tests to work in Test Explorer:
                https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1617

Comment: The tests will show up in Test Explorer after you build the project.

Comment: They didn't show up for me when I built my project even after cleaning the solution first. They didn't appear until I did the steps above. This point was off topic anyway and I was just trying to add some useful information here to anyone also finding themselves in the same situation.